# Bokeh - Is it possible to make axis_label dynamic?

Tags: bokeh

I have a simple scatter plot that is defined by:

```
p.scatter('x', 'y',source=source)
p.xaxis.axis_label = "price"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "quantity"
```

I am dynamically changing the data displayed by having the user select whichever variable they want to display from a select widget.  Is it be possible set p.xaxis.axis_label to the value that is returned when the user selects an option from the select widget?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it with the `on_change` callback method from your instance of the select widget. For example:

```
def update_label(attr, old, new):    
    p.xaxis.axis_label = new    

myselect.on_change('value', update_label)
```